# Подобрать параметр, максимизирующий F-меру

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Подбираю параметр `k` (целое число), чтобы умножить порог классификации `T`.
То есть, `T = 0.1k`.

Есть три алгоритма. Нужно к каждому подобрать такое `k`, при котором F-мера (`f1_score`) максимальна.

Написал код, который выводит все ответы, но тогда можно просто глазами пробежать, а как мне сразу максимизировать?

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score, f1_score`
k = np.arange(1,11,1)
for i in k:
    T=0.1*i
    for actual, predicted, descr in zip([actual_1, actual_10, actual_11], 
                                    [predicted_1 > T, predicted_10 > T, predicted_11 > T], 
                                    ["Typical:", "Avoids FP:", "Avoids FN:"]):
        print(descr, i, "f1 =", f1_score(actual, predicted))
```

Исходные данные были такими:

`actual_1 = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
                    0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
                    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
predicted_1 = np.array([ 0.41310733,  0.43739138,  0.22346525,  0.46746017,  0.58251177,
            0.38989541,  0.43634826,  0.32329726,  0.01114812,  0.41623557,
            0.54875741,  0.48526472,  0.21747683,  0.05069586,  0.16438548,
            0.68721238,  0.72062154,  0.90268312,  0.46486043,  0.99656541,
            0.59919345,  0.53818659,  0.8037637 ,  0.272277  ,  0.87428626,
            0.79721372,  0.62506539,  0.63010277,  0.35276217,  0.56775664])
actual_10 = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
                0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
                1.,  1.,  1.])
predicted_10 = np.array([ 0.29340574, 0.47340035,  0.1580356 ,  0.29996772,  0.24115457,  0.16177793,
                         0.35552878,  0.18867804,  0.38141962,  0.20367392,  0.26418924, 0.16289102, 
                         0.27774892,  0.32013135,  0.13453541, 0.39478755,  0.96625033,  0.47683139,

                         0.51221325,  0.48938235, 0.57092593,  0.21856972,  0.62773859,  0.90454639,  0.19406537,
                         0.32063043,  0.4545493 ,  0.57574841,  0.55847795 ])
actual_11 = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
                0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
predicted_11 = np.array([ 0.35929566, 0.61562123,  0.71974688,  0.24893298,  0.19056711,  0.89308488,
            0.71155538,  0.00903258,  0.51950535,  0.72153302,  0.45936068,  0.20197229,  0.67092724,
                         0.81111343,  0.65359427,  0.70044585,  0.61983513,  0.84716577,  0.8512387 ,

                         0.86023125,  0.7659328 ,  0.70362246,  0.70127618,  0.8578749 ,  0.83641841,

                         0.62959491,  0.90445368])`

Comment: Что у вас за модели (алгоритмы)? Как вы их обучаете? В данной формулировке - мало что понятно...

Comment: Добавил исходники, модели уже обучены, тут нужно просто реализовать подбор параметра, который бы максимизировал F-меру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [scipy.optimize.minimize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Пример:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(k, y_true, y_pred_proba):
    return -f1_score(y_true, y_pred_proba >= k)

res_1 = minimize(f, [0.5], (actual_1, predicted_1), method="Nelder-Mead", tol=1e-5)
res_10 = minimize(f, [0.5], (actual_10, predicted_10), method="Nelder-Mead", tol=1e-5)
res_11 = minimize(f, [0.5], (actual_11, predicted_11), method="Nelder-Mead", tol=1e-5)
```

---

результаты:

```
In [91]: res_1
Out[91]:
 final_simplex: (array([[0.5      ],
       [0.5000061]]), array([-0.82758621, -0.82758621]))
           fun: -0.8275862068965518
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 38
           nit: 13
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([0.5])

In [92]: res_10
Out[92]:
 final_simplex: (array([[0.45     ],
       [0.4499939]]), array([-0.76923077, -0.76923077]))
           fun: -0.7692307692307692
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 42
           nit: 15
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([0.45])

In [93]: res_11
Out[93]:
 final_simplex: (array([[0.525    ],
       [0.5250061]]), array([-0.78787879, -0.78787879]))
           fun: -0.787878787878788
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 37
           nit: 13
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([0.525])
```

---

нас интересует значение с ключем `"x"`:

```
In [94]: res_10["x"]
Out[94]: array([0.45])

In [95]: res_11["x"]
Out[95]: array([0.525])
```